# Is there an ESLint rule for ES6 style shorthanded functions in objects?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

In ES6 we no longer have to use the `function` keyword when our function is a property in an object:

```
const obj = {
    hello: function() { console.log("world!"); }
};
```

becomes

```
const obj = {
    hello() { console.log("world!"); }
};
```

Is there an ESLint rule to enforce using the new style?  I don't see anything like it in the [ES6 rule list](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/#ecmascript-6).

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-shorthand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule you're looking for is `object-shorthand`. From [the docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-shorthand):

> Each of the following properties would warn:
>
> ```
> /*eslint object-shorthand: "error"*/
> /*eslint-env es6*/
>
> var foo = {
>     w: function() {},
>     x: function *() {},
>     [y]: function() {},
>     z: z
> };
> ```
>
> In that case the expected syntax would have been:
>
> ```
> /*eslint object-shorthand: "error"*/
> /*eslint-env es6*/
>
> var foo = {
>     w() {},
>     *x() {},
>     [y]() {},
>     z
> };
> ```

Comment: Thanks!  My brain was searching for the word `function` when looking through the docs - must have gone right by this.